# useState is reverting to older value and not updating

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using the Next.js catch all route ('[[...slug]]') to create a page that includes an image based on a parameter in the url. If there are no parameters in the url, the variables are set to a default variables to create the page.
In the [[...slug]].tsx file, I set the two variables to either the parameters in the url, or the default parameters, with an if statement.

```
  const router = useRouter();
  let storyType = "";
  let storyBrand = "";

  const storyData = router.query.slug;

  if (!storyData) {
    storyType = "defaultStoryType";
    storyBrand = "defaultStoryBrand";
  } else {
    storyType = storyData[0];
    storyBrand = storyData[1];
  }
```

I then send these variables to a component

```
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <DemoHeader storybrand={storyBrand} storytype={storyType} />
      ....
```

In the component, I use useState to make sure the image is able to load. If it can't be found, I want to change the source of the image to a default source. The parameters are passed to the component correctly.

```
function DemoImage(props) {
  const { src, alt, width, height } = props;
  console.log("this is the source in demoimage before useState: " + src);

  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(src);
  console.log("this is imgSrc after useState:     " + imgSrc);

  const [imgSrc2, setImgSrc2] = useState("/img/demo/chase/logo.png");
  console.log("this is imgSrc2:    " + imgSrc2);

  const handleOnError = () => {
    console.log("could not find imgSrc");
    setImgSrc(
      "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=This+is+error+image"
    );
  };
  const handleOnError2 = () => {
    console.log("could not find imgSrc2");
    setImgSrc2("https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=error+Image2");
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Image
        //{...props}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        src={imgSrc}
        alt={alt}
        onError={handleOnError}
      />
      <Image
        width={width}
        height={height}
        src={imgSrc2}
        alt={alt}
        onError={handleOnError2}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

The problem is that it goes through the component twice. The first time must be something nextjs does, because it does not even test if the image can be loaded, and variables are not updated with the slug. And the second time through the component it does not reset useState, and therefore appears to use the default values as per the console.log output below. If I reset the useState, it goes through an endless loop.

```
FIRST TIME-DOES NOT USE SLUG-IMGSRC SET TO DEFAULT
This is storyType from slug in slugtsx:  defaultStoryType
This is the source in demoimage before useState: /img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png
This is imgSrc after useState:     /img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png
This is imgSrc2:    /img/demo/chase/logo.png
SECOND TIME-HAS SLUG AND CORRECT SRC-DOES NOT SET IMGSRC
This is storyType from slug in slugtsx:  wsbm
This is the source in demoimage before useState: /img/demo/chase/logo.png
This is imgSrc after useState:     /img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png
This is imgSrc2:    /img/demo/chase/logo.png
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fdemo%2FdefaultStoryBrand%2Flogo.png&w=640&q=75 400 (Bad Request) Image (async)   setValueForProperty @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:855 updateDOMProperties @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9738    updateProperties @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:10143  commitUpdate @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:11047…
could not find imgSrc 
This is the source in demoimage before useState: /img/demo/chase/logo.png
This is imgSrc after useState:     https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=This+is+error+image
```

For debugging purposes, I duplicated some of the code using a set variable (imgSrc2) so you can see that it does work correctly if useState is correct.

Can I reset useState without causing an endless loop? Or is there a way to set properly set useState so it uses the updated parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Almost ***all*** of those console logs are unintentional side-effects outside the component lifecycle, so unexpected results shouldn't surprise you. What is it *specifically* you think there's an issue updating?

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate that the first time through it uses the default, for some reason it does not get the src value from the slug. The second time through it uses the default as well, even though it does have the src value from the slug. The setImgSrc does not set to the value in src.

Comment: My point was that you've unintentional side-effects, so it's very likely that all but one set of logs is incorrect. What are the prop values when the component is *actually* rendered to the DOM? Use a `useEffect` hook to log these values so there's a 1-1 relation between renders and logs.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't understand. The page is currently displaying the error image because for some reason the imgSrc is not being set to src. But if the console logs are correct, the correct src is being passed into the component, it is simply that useState is not using the src to update imgSrc

Comment: (1) Story type from slug is `"defaultStoryType"`, I'll assume the story brand is `"defaultStoryBrand"` since that's what's in the src string, (2) `props.src` and `imgSrc` are both `"/img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png"`, (3) `Image` is passed `src={imgSrc}` and has an error and calls `handleOnError`, (4) `handleOnError` updates `imgSrc` to `"https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=This+is+error+image"`, (5) `imgSrc` state value is now `"https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=This+is+error+image"`. I don't see where any state update issue exists.

Comment: the issue is that defaultStoryType and ..Brand are NOT correct. I have that in the initial if in case there is nothing in the slug.
So it runs through once without getting the slug, not sure why. The issue is that it then sets imgSrc to the default src, using defaultStoryBrand.
The second time it runs through it has the correct stortybrand from the slug - "chase", and the correct src for the image "/img/demo/chase/logo.png". however useState does not use this (src)  when setting the imgSrc. So as you noted, it is set incorrectly with the old default src /img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png

Comment: Sorry, I noted no such incorrect setting of state. I just don't see any inconsistency from the logs. All the logs appear to be correct from what I'd expect them to be from the passed props value. If you are saying any prop values are incorrect then you need to look higher in the ReactTree to see where any passed prop value becomes *not* what you are expecting it to be. Starting from `const storyData = router.query.slug;` is what I'd suggest.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Do you see these two lines in the above output?
This is the source in demoimage before useState: /img/demo/chase/logo.png
This is imgSrc after useState:     /img/demo/defaultStoryBrand/logo.png

The src is "...chase.." as it said. the imgSrc after useState should be /img/demo/chase/logo.png

it is useState is not setting it correctly.

You notice how the first time through it does not try to load the image? I believe it is just nextjs compiling or something. But I don't understand why it retains the value.  
can I reset imgSrc?

Comment: That's how React states work. Once they are initialized they retain their value until you enqueue a state update to change it. I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by "retains the value" or what needs to be "reset", or why that's an issue.

Comment: because I want it to be set to the "src" variable. the src variable is correct, at least if the console.log is correct. And yet imgSrc is not updating with the src variable.
How can I force it to change?

Comment: Call `setImgSrc` and pass the new value you want to update the `imgSrc` state to. ‍♂️

Comment: that is what I am doing, and it is not working.  src is correct, and yet imgSrc is not updating, as per the log.

Comment: It's not working? Your logs say otherwise. See (4) & (5) in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146093/usestate-is-reverting-to-older-value-and-not-updating#comment130911542_74146093) where `handleOnError` is called and enqueues a state update. If you are enqueueing a state update somewhere else you need to include the relevant code. It's starting to feel like we're not going to make any progress here, either you are not providing a [mcve] or we're not understanding what any issue is that you are seeing.

Comment: handleOnError should not be called. it is only being called because it is not setting imgSrc correctly.  The src URL has the correct image src in "src". However it never gets to imgSrc. I understand if you don't want to continue this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a useEffect statement:

```
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(src);
  useEffect(() => {
      setImgSrc(src);
    }, [imgSrc, src]);
```

I still don't understand why it changes, it should always have the same value from the slug. When it changes useEffect will make sure that imgSrc is always correct.